# OAuth2 in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm trying to authenticate with an external service in my Flutter Web application, and it seems [this](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2) is the officially endorsed library. However, for the code grant flow, the `listen()` method used for automatically retrieving the token relies on either uni_links or webview_flutter, none of which support web. I've been looking around and haven't found any example of a working implementation of OAuth2 in Flutter web.

Comment: What server do you use ? What specific usage do you have for OAuth2 ? Why simple http request can't solve this ? ;)

Comment: @MathisFouques all OAuth2 servers implement the same standard. My question is not specific to a particular server. I'm asking how to listen for the callback and retrieve the token on Flutter web. The simple http can't solve this because it has no functionality to listen to incoming events.

Comment: I think it might be done with the dart:html library..

Comment: Seriously? No one will touch this?

Comment: Hey - I too am looking for something similar. In my case the OAuth2 implementation was done using the KeyCloak server. Let me know if you have any updates. Thanks!

Comment: I have been using fullter_appauth and they have a PR for adding web support but I'm looking around for other repos or info on this topic as this is going to be a hot topic this year, if flutter web (in beta) is going to get any real production use, we need these tools to be cross platform and simple, secure in our flutter apps with all the crazy if (kIsWeb) code all over the place.  I'm surprsed the flutter team is not looking at tools like this, its almost as if oauth2 needs to be as easy to use as http client.  We almost need requirements and some standards in a single place.  Happy to test!