# Unpack OAuth2 response in a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

Since there apparently is no way to implement a way to complete a OAuth2 code grand flow in Flutter Web (because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946743/oauth2-in-flutter-web)), as a workaround, I'm using a firebase cloud function to retrieve the token. Basically the redirectUrl is a cloud function that should capture the token and store it in firestore. I'm trying to identify the fields, and just print them out to console first. This is my function:

```
export const printRequest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
    console.log("Hello from Firebase! headers:" + request.headers + ", body:cd" + request.body + " and " + request.params);
    console.log(request.body)
    cors(request, response, async () => {
        const body = request.body;
        console.log("access token")
        console.log(body.access_token)
    })
    response.send("All done");
});
```

which, in the Firebase cloud functions console reads like this:

```
>Hello from Firebase! headers:[object Object], body:cd[object Object] and [object Object] 
>undefined
```

How do I unpack the server response?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body));
```

Full example [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#functions-log-helloworld-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the token is just a URL parameter, so getting that is just a matter of splitting the string.

```
export const printRequest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    let urele = request.url.split("code=")[1];
    console.log("final code " + urele.toString().split("&")[0]);
    console.log(request.read.toString);
    cors(request, response, async () => {
        const body = request.body;
        console.log(body);
    });
    response.send("All done");
});
```